# Worker Thread Task completion callback not available for IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, service, intentservice, worker-thread

As per developer guidelines, IntentService starts worker thread and destroys self. Next task is taken care by worker thread.

Worker thread do not notify into IntentService that task has been completed and is getting stopped.

Your code into onDestroy gets immediate invocation once service started and destroyed following start which is on Main Thread.

How to resolve issue when you do not get worker thread task completion callback into IntentService ?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onDestroy()` to know when the `IntentService` is shutting down. However, if you need to know this then you probably don't want to use `IntentService`. Just use `Service` and create and manage your own background `Thread`s. You can then manage the lifetime of the `Service` however you want. `IntentService` isn't always the right approach. It is just a rapper around `Service` that provides some very specific worker `Thread` management.